# Java specification, where does it say that sorting for Arrays should be stable?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, jls

Basically, I've just been reading javadoc for Arrays : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

and it says:

> The documentation for the methods contained in this class includes
>   briefs description of the implementations. Such descriptions should be
>   regarded as implementation notes, rather than parts of the
>   specification. Implementors should feel free to substitute other
>   algorithms, so long as the specification itself is adhered to. (For
>   example, the algorithm used by sort(Object[]) does not have to be a
>   MergeSort, but it does have to be stable.)

basically it says that this doc is just implementation notes. But it mentions that implementation anyway should adhere to the specification. In particular, that sorting of Arrays should be stable. So I'm curious , what specification they're talking about (is it JLS?) and where in it it is said that sorting of arrays should be stable or anything related to that?

Comment: The javadoc of sort() says: This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort. It says that **before** the implementation note. That's the specification.

Comment: @JBNizet so javadoc **is** a specification? But that doesn't make sense? Right? Because  javadoc is just implementation notes on -sun- Oracle implementation of Java language and there is no such requirement that any other implementations should have `Arrays` class or `sort` method at all.

Comment: Yes, there is. If every Java implementation came with a different standard API, or if every standard API did something different, you would not be able to rely on any standard API anymore, would you? The part **before** the title "implementation notes" is not an implementation note. Otherwise, it would come after the title "implementation notes". The Arrays.sort() method probably predates the JSR/JEP organization, but if it was introduced now, it would be part of a JSR or JEP which would have specified what sort() must do.

Comment: Well, yes, I wouldn't be able to rely on any standard API, because there wouldn't be such a thing. What amazes me is that there is such a thing as a standard API. Do you have any sources which mention that there is/shall be any standard API at all? Also it basically means that every java language implementation must support the standard API, so if the API gets updated, then all the implementations must support that too?

Comment: Go to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/. What does the title and the sentence below the title say? *Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8
API Specification
This document is the API specification for the Java™ Platform, Standard Edition.* Java is not just a language. It's a platform. Several platforms actually: Java SE, Java EE, Java ME.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-), in particular this sentence:

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Comment: I assume he is already aware about the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) page as he quoted text from the same page. He is more interested in any reference to JLS I think.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar maybe, but the JLS is not about sorting algorithms.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar exactly. I'm quoting  javadoc saying about some specification. That's that specification what I'm interested in, which I belive shouldn't be the javadoc itself. Specifically, javadoc says: "Implementors should feel free to substitute other algorithms, so long as the specification itself is adhered to. (For example, the algorithm used by sort(Object[]) does not have to be a MergeSort, but it does have to be stable.)"  - so it looks like there is some specification which says that sorting should be stable.

Comment: The javadoc itself is the specification that is being referred to.  The javadocs are the primary specification for the behavior of the Java class libraries.